# How to use PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd to query and table and update a PowerShell $variable?

Tags: sql-server, query, powershell

How do I update a PowerShell variable using an Invoke-Sqlcmd statement?

Eg.

```
$PSVariable

Import-Module sqlserver

$QueryStatement = "SELECT $PSVariable = Max(Data) FROM MyDatabase"
    
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyServer\Instance" -Query $QueryStatement
```

Not sure what is off with this code. I am new to the PowerShell sqlserver module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this a go...

```
$Query = "SELECT Max(Data) as MaxData FROM MyDatabase"
$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyServer\Instance" -Query $Query | select -expand MaxData 

write-host $Result
```

Comment: This did answer my question. Is there a way I can store my result to a SQL variable like ```Declare @MyVariable int;``` then update that and return the result?